# How to set the volume size of aws ec2 for root volume in cloud formation template

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

How to I change the Disk size of the for the Root Disk volume in Cloud formation template

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to do? Which template? You haven't posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/dev/xvda is your root volume, so just add BlockDeviceMappng for it with the desired size.

```
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        # /root volume
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: true
            VolumeSize: 256
            VolumeType: gp2
```